# WP MS: How to query over the network

Tags: multisite, query-posts, query, wpdb, blog-id

I have a WP 3.8.1 Multisite installation with 3 blogs, they're all in one db, prefixed `wp_`, `wp_2_` and `wp_3_`.

In a template in `wp_` I try to to display all posts from `wp_`, `wp_2_` and `wp_3_` which have a category *xxx* attached. I want to display the posts chronologically. I tried this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM $wpdb->posts
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->posts.ID= $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id=$wpdb->terms.term_id WHERE $wpdb->terms.name = 'xxx'
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
```

This works only for the current blog, ie it doesn't include `wp_2_` and `wp_3_`.

How do I retrieve all posts with category *xxx* from `wp_`, `wp_2_`, `wp_3_` (instead of only `wp_`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each site in a Multisite network is considered to be exactly that -- a separate *site*. All the `$wpdb` values (eg, `$wpdb->posts`) are distinct for each site.

You can use [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) and [`restore_current_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog) to get content (posts, etc) from the various sites[*] in your network:

```
$sites = array( 1, 2, 3, );
$all_posts = array();
$args = array( 'category_name' => 'xxx', );
foreach( $sites as $site ) {
    switch_to_blog( $site );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        // Better get the post's permalink, since it's site-dependent
        $post->permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );
        $all_posts[] = $post;
    }
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

This will get you an array of all the posts from each of your sites -- each one will appear in the array as a [`WP_Post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) object. To sort them all by date, you can use PHP's [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) function and compare the `$post->post_date` or `$post->post_date_gmt` values.

#### References

- [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog)
- [`restore_current_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog)
- [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts)
- [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)
- [`WP_Post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post)
- [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort)

---

[*]: Initially WordPress used the terminology "a *site* of *blogs*". Later it was refined to "a *network* of *sites*", but some of the function names still reflect the old ways.

Comment: I don't see the switch_to_blog() call in your code. I guess it's supposed to be called after the first foreach line?

Comment: and it's 'category_name' rather than 'category'.

Comment: Whoops, fixed! Thanks for pointing that out. (Also added the `restore_current_blog()` call at the end of the outer `foreach()`.)